# React Native Router Flux Transition Speed

Tags: animation, react-native, react-native-router-flux

**My Issue**

React Native Router Flux scene transition on android is painfully slow. I have a listview with images with about 80 rows of restaurant titles. Each row has a touchable button that pushes a detail scene of the restaurant. List loading speed is fine, so I don't think that's the bottleneck. I have disabled the "push" animation (duration={1}) and it seems to help out some. However I am wanting to disable the animation of sliding back into the listview as well. How can I achieve pretty much no animations on android? *Action.push() & Action.pop()*?

**My Code**

```
<Scene key="DirectoryDetailAndroid" duration={1} navigationBarStyle={styleNavigationBarStyle} backTitle={backButtonIcon} titleStyle={styleTitleStyle} type="push"  hideBackImage={true} component={DirectoryDetailAndroid} title="Directory Detail" />
```

**What I have tried**

I have tried a scene reset, making sure there were no console.log's in my redux anywhere. I have implemented the interaction manager on the scene I push to as well.

*Side note*, if anyone knows of a better solution for android slow scene transitions or different navigator component for android, I'm all ears.

Comment: Same here... also made sure no console.logs and used InteractionManager as well. iPhone 7 = okay, iPhone 6 = not okay, Samsung Galaxy S6 painfully slow. Out of curiosity, are you doing any network requests in your restaurant detail view?

Comment: I am making a network request inside my detail view. I have now just switched over to ex-navigation in favor of react native router flux. Now navigation on my old S3 is working pretty smooth. I also was using the interaction manager and making sure no log's were being fired off.

Comment: That's good news! On the other hand I tried out a quick useNativeDriver mod on react-native-router-flux: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/10289#issuecomment-272992628 and noticed an improvement as well. I wouldn't call mine "smooth" but more like "not as painful", haha.

Comment: I might have to give that a whirl. On iPhone, this package worked like a dream, I really enjoyed it. Have you tried making setting the duration time to a lower number? "duration={1}" in your router. That seemed to help android out quite a bit, but when the navigator popped transition speed dipped a ton.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried every optimization in the book... Bit the bullet and tried swapping out react-native-router-flux for Ex-navigation for the slow route. Ex-navigation has no delay and I'm getting "smooth" now. It's too bad I'm way too deep in my project with a deadline to switch, but it seems Ex-navigation is definitely the way to go. SUPER SMOOTH, on every phone too...